# How to arrange every n rows into columns using awk

Tags: command-line, grep, awk

I have a tab-separated data like this:

```
a 2
b 3
c 4
d 6
e 8
f 9
g 10
h 11
i 12
...
```

My desired output should look like this:

```
a 2 d 6 g 10 
b 3 e 8 h 11
c 4 f 9 i 12
```

How can I do this, for instance using awk.

Thanks in advance.
Sincerely,
nsingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '{a[FNR%3] = a[FNR%3] == "" ? $0 : a[FNR%3] "\t" $0} END{for(i=1;i<=3;i++) print a[i%3]}' data.tsv
a   2   d   6   g   10
b   3   e   8   h   11
c   4   f   9   i   12
```

Another possibility is the `rs` utility - probably not installed by default, but available on Ubuntu from package `rs`.

```
$ rs -e -C -t 0 3 < data.tsv
a   2   d   6   g   10  
b   3   e   8   h   11  
c   4   f   9   i   12
```

where

- `-e` treat each input line as an array element
- `-C` output columns separated by a single tab
- `-t` transpose input columns to rows
- `0 3` use as many rows as necessary with 3 columns

Another option is the `pr` command

Ex. print in 3 columns, suppressing headers and footers:

```
$ pr -T -3 < data.tsv
a   2       d   6       g   10
b   3       e   8       h   11
c   4       f   9       i   12
```

If you want the columns separated by exactly one TAB character:

```
$ pr -s$'\t' -T -3 < data.tsv
a   2   d   6   g   10
b   3   e   8   h   11
c   4   f   9   i   12
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about `awk` but it can be done simply using `split` and `paste`.

Let us assume a file named `data` contains our rows. First to split it into 3 lines chunks:

```
$ split -l 3 data output-
```

Then to put these chunks together:

```
$ paste -d ' ' output-*

a 2 d 6 g 10
b 3 e 8 h 11
c 4 f 9 i 12
```

And remember to remove `output-` files.